# Best way to integrate Meteorjs, angular and Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm looking for the quickest way to integrate Meteor.js with Angular.js and Bootstrap.js.
I've seen Urigo:Angular but seems there is no quick integration with Bootstrap.
Any advise about it?
Thank you 
ny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just using the Bootstrap's CSS, Ethaan's answer is a complete one.

But if you want to use also the JS, you should also use libraries like [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) or [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/)

Also here, angular-meteor is agnostic to those and you can add both exactly like you would with any other AngularJS application.

You have 3 options of including those libraries into your Meteor application:

1. Add it with the [meteor-bower package](https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-bower)
2. Create a Meteor package that includes those files
3. Pull request those libraries to publish Meteor packages themselves - look at Davdv's talk about it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-idz8UPtDM)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and yes I'm interested in using the JS.
I'll use one of the two suggested libraries, at a first glance sems that AngularStrap is less complete than ui-boostrap but probably is just an early opinion...

Comment: @Urigo meteor-bower package is broken for Meteor 1.3 as per the link

Answer (score 3):

Just add it using [meteor add](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteoradd)

try with

```
meteor add bootstrap
```

or

```
meteor add twbs:bootstrap
```

take a look into [atmosphere bootstrap search](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=bootstrap)