# How to set up Meteor-Angular with Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I am at a bit of a loss so far as to how to set up my Meteor-Angular project with Twitter Bootstrap.

So far I have:

1. Installed Bower

   ```
   meteor add mquandalle:bower
   ```
2. Added a dependency to `bower.json`:

   ```
   {
     ...
     "dependencies": {
       "angular-bootstrap": "0.14.3"
     },
     ...
   }
   ```
3. Added dependecy in my project:

   ```
   angular.module('myApp', [..., 'ui.bootstrap']);
   ```
4. Added the following directive in public/main.css (as recommended [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)):

   ```
   .nav, .pagination, .carousel, .panel-title a { cursor: pointer; }
   ```
5. Set up the tooltip example from the [UI-Bootstrap project site](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) within my application

When I then run my app, I see the following being included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/bower/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js?bdad9e18333da6ba34b675927f4b74cb53651baf"></script>
```

However, it appears as though no style resources (i.e., the CSS files and assets) are available, as I do see the expected dynamics of the content, but without the expected formatting.

What steps am I missing?

What other ways of setting up Bootstrap in Meteor/Angular are there?

NB:
I tried to follow recommendations [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28574234/1162278).

Answer (score 0):

Adding `twbs:bootstrap` by running

```
 meteor add twbs:bootstrap
```

appears to have fixed the problem.

If anyone can confirm that this is the intended approach or whether I duplicated parts of Bootstrap that way, that would still be welcome.